# Victim Cache larger than L1 cache

Tags: caching, vhdl, simulation, processor

I currently working on a school project and design competition for a memory cache. I have to follow certain constraints on L1 cache sizes, but there is no specification on the victim cache size. This is all in VHDL simulation.

So I'm trying to ask if there are any references, papers, journals, etc... that might mention a processor that a Victim Cache that is larger than the L1 cache size.

Thanks you,
I have looked on google, but alot of my searches pull up lecture slides and not papers.

Answer (score 0):

The IBM POWER architectures used a kind of L3/victim cache hybrid. I Googled a little and found that in the POWER5 and POWER7 the victim cache was significantly larger than the L1 *however* the victim cache was intended for the L2 cache in the first place.